# Open new teamviewer connections in tabbed window?

Tags: teamviewer

I have searched and cannot find any useful information. I am trying to get my teamviewer connections to open up in the same window as another tab. I have this ability already on one computer but the other does not do it. I cannot find the setting to change this, and I am not sure how it ever got turned on, but I like it.

Any ideas how to turn this tabbing on or off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Extras menu > Options
2. Click Remote Control section on left
3. Click Open new connections in tabs

Comment: Could you please improve this answer with better explanation, rather than just naming the items to click ? Please follow this link to understand how to post a valuable answer : http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Also worth pointing out that this only works for TeamViewer running on Windows.  Not valid for Mac.

Comment: For osx, I suggest you to apply this link: https://community.teamviewer.com/English/discussion/2816/multitask-more-easily-with-remote-control-tabs-for-macos